# Update Django context variable using Ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I've spent quite some time trying to find a solution, but I am fairly new to Django and I just can't seem to wrap my head around this.

In my detail view I pass the product I want to display (product) in the template and also the first product type of the product (pid).

When a new product type is selected via a dropdown box in detail.html, I need to update the product type context variable without reloading the page, and so **that I can send it to cart_add view as a parameter in the URL**.

I figured I can do this using Ajax. I can display the value of the selected product type, but I do not know how to update the context variable to this new value.

**views.py**

```
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug)
    product_types = ProductType.objects.filter(product=product, available=True)
    pid = product_types[0]
    mylist = []
    for product_type in product_types:
        mylist.append(dict((x.base, x.value) for x in ProductAttribute.objects.filter(product_type=product_type)))
    category = Category.objects.get(id=product.category.id)
    parent_category = category.parent_category
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'shop/product/detail.html',
        {'parent_category':parent_category, 'category':category, 'product': product, 'cart_product_form': cart_product_form, 'product_types': product_types, 'mylist': mylist, 'pid':pid}

def load_product_type(request):
    product_type_id = request.GET.get('product_type_pk')
    product_type = ProductType.objects.get(id=product_type_id)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/product-type.html', {'product_type': product_type})
```

**product-type.html**

```
{{product_type.id}}
```

**detail.html**

```
<select name="product_type" id="product_type" data-product_type-url="{% url 'shop:ajax_load_product_type' %}" required class="form-control">
                {% for product_type in product_types %}
                    <option value="{{product_type.id}}">{{product_type.reference}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
</select>
        
<p class="product-id" id="product-id"></p>  
        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#product_type").change(function () {
        var url = $("#product_type").attr("data-product_type-url");  
        var product_type_pk = $(this).val();  
        
        $.ajax({                       
            url: url,                    
            data: {
                'product_type_pk': product_type_pk,       
                 },
                success: function (data) {
                    // instead of showing it in the template, I want something like
                    // pid = data
                    $("#product-id").html(data);  
                 }
            });
        });
        </script>

        // This is where I want to assign to pid the new selected product type
        <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' pid.id  %}" method="post">
            {{ cart_product_form }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
        </form>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You cannot replace context variables from the client side because they **don't even exist** for the client. The client doesn't know how the html is rendered (all of this is done at server side) and it really shouldn't.

Comment: Any idea @AbdulAzizBarkat on how to do it server-side?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Change the action attribute of the form? Just send the url of the form in the response and set it using javascript.

Comment: I want to change the pid to the selected product_type.id

Comment: You want to change the action attribute of the form, yes?

Comment: yes I want to **update** the action attribute of the form

Answer (score 0):

I assume you simply want to change the action attribute of the form. Firstly set an id on your form:

```
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' pid.id  %}" method="post" id="my-form">
```

Now in your template `product-type.html` write:

```
{% url 'cart:cart_add' product_type.id  %}
```

Now in your javascript in the success function (for the ajax):

```
$("#my-form").attr("action", data);
```

> **Note**: Perhaps sending a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
> would be more indicative then simply sending the data by rendering it in a template

Comment: Now that I look back at it perhaps you didn't even need ajax. Wasn't `product_type_pk` already the pk you needed? You could have constructed the new url in javascript.

Comment: yes exactly. How do I do that with product_type_pk? Thx for your help

Comment: @SofiaLazrak in fact you don't even need to do that. You could have simply put the select tag part in your form and just post to the one url instead of changing the url according to the selected option.

Comment: Something Like:
`code`
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add'  %}" method="post" id="my-form">
                <select name="product_type" id="product_type" data-product_type-url="{% url 'shop:ajax_load_product_type' %}" required class="form-control">
                    {% for product_type in product_types %}
                        <option value="{{product_type.id}}">{{product_type.reference}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            {{ cart_product_form }}
           ...
        </form>
`code`

Comment: @SofiaLazrak instead of doing all this just add the field directly to your form class....

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat for your help. It is strange how I did not think of doing it the simple way. I added the select directly to the form and I could then easily pass the selected product type to the url. Thank you again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229361/discussion-between-sofia-lazrak-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).